# How to setup export names at runtime in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

In a subdir i got a bunch of modules with filenames unknown to their code
They all talk to some hardware on a port and client number declared by the filename.
say: sub/p0c0.js, sub/p0c1.js, sub/p5c5.js

In each module I need a function exported as the filename.
Like:
  exports.p0c0 = function() {}; //in sub/p0c0.js, exports.p5c5 = function() {}; //in sub/p5c5.js

It is the user who copies and renames the files into sub from a set of standard modules
like: copy 8ch_Light_damper.js to sub/p1c2.js And thereby defines where the hardware is connected.

I can extract the filename from module.filename. But how do I use that in the exports.

Answer (score 2):

Use indexer notation:

```
exports[myVar] = myValue;
```

Comment: Don't get it. Do you mean var f = extract from module.filename; function xxx() {} exports[f] = xxx;

Comment: @user: Exactly.  Or just `module.exports[f] = function() { ... };`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Newer had figured that myself :).